# Home Bball court of concrete

Tags: concrete, slab, rebar

I am looking to make a basketball court in my yard. Probably gonna be around 36’x25’. I think a concrete truck can bring about 10 yards of concrete. Would a 3.5” thick slab be strong enough? Do I need rebar? Would I be able to park a car/minivan on it?
Thank you

Comment: Concrete trucks usually have friends, so you can get as much delivered as you need, via multiple trucks. Rebar is dirt cheap compared to the cost of concrete, you'd be crazy not to - but put it in right (not just laying on the bottom.) Given the cost of concrete, some attention to what you are pouring the concrete on is also advisable (drainage, etc.)

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/construction/cubic-yards-calculator.php  -  Calculates it to be 9.72 cubic yards.